# Putting text over biblatex bibliography header

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm getting really frustrated trying to put my name over the bibtex bibliography. 
Is there anyway I can do that?

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true
    ]{biblatex}             
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{ThKZ2002,
  %required: author,title,journal,year
  %optional: volume,number,pages,month,note,doi/url+urldate
  author={Goldschlag, David and Reed, Michael and Syverson, Paul},
  title={{Onion Routing for Anonymous and Private
Internet Connections}},
  journal={Communications of the ACM},
  year={1999},
  volume={42},
  number={2},
  month={feb},
} 
\begin{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{raggedright} 
  \nocite{*}                        
  \printbibliography               

\end{raggedright}
\end{document}
```

There's no way I can find to put text over the Bibtex header "References". Is it possible though?

Comment: What do you mean by 'over'? Do you mean `\printbibliography[title={My Name}]`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean to change the title of the bibliography but to add text over the title of it.

Comment: Well, the title is like a `\section`/`\chapter` heading, how would you want to add text over it?

Comment: I hoped there was a way of doing that... I just need to put my name on that bibliography page that's everything. Is there at least a way to put my name under the bibliography? Either way is fine really...

Comment: Maybe if you "downgrade" the bibliphraphy to a section `\clearpage
text before bibiography
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]  `

Comment: @moewe Perhaps she wanted something like `textpos` to overlay her name over the Bibliography title???

Comment: You can do `My Name \printbibliography[heading=none]` or `\chapter*{My Name}\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]`. Or `\defbibnote{myname}{My Name}\printbibliography[prenote=myname]` it all depends on what output exactly you want.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to "downgrade" the bibliography heading from a chapter to a section. This way it does not start a new page and you can put whatever you want before it on the page.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true
    ]{biblatex}             
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{ThKZ2002,
  %required: author,title,journal,year
  %optional: volume,number,pages,month,note,doi/url+urldate
  author={Goldschlag, David and Reed, Michael and Syverson, Paul},
  title={{Onion Routing for Anonymous and Private
Internet Connections}},
  journal={Communications of the ACM},
  year={1999},
  volume={42},
  number={2},
  month={feb},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}  

\clearpage
\noindent text before bibiography
\begin{raggedright}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]             
\end{raggedright}
\end{document}
```